# Using SUM so that NULL in columns make sum NULL

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I have a a table with a column groups INTEGER NULL. It has values

### groups

5
7
`<NULL>`

If I do a select sum(groups) form table_name
I would get 12. How can I get null, when  the column being summed has a null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option:

```
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(groups) THEN SUM(groups) ELSE NULL END
```

Comment: Looks good: count(*) gives the total number of rows, count(groups) gives the number of non-null groups. If these are different then you must have a null or two.

Answer (score 2):

```
select
  case when exists (select groups from table where groups is null) then null
       else select sum(groups) from table
  end as grp_sum
```

Comment: You can still come up with a nice stored procedure using cursors :)

Comment: btw, `groups = null` should probably be `groups is null`, at least on postgresql.