# SQL query to return NULL for SUM(expression) whenever an included value IS NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, null, aggregate-functions

For MySQL, I want a query that returns a SUM of an expression, EXCEPT that I want the returned value to be NULL if any of the expressions included in the SUM are NULL.  (The normal operation of SUM is to ignore NULL values.

Here's a simple test case that illustrates

```
CREATE TABLE t4 (fee VARCHAR(3), fi INT);
INSERT INTO t4 VALUES ('fo',10),('fo',200),('fo',NULL),('fum',400);

SELECT fee, SUM(fi) AS sum_fi FROM t4 GROUP BY fee
```

This returns exactly the result set I expect:

```
fee sum_fi
--- ------
fo     210
fum    400
```

What I want is a query that returns a DIFFERENT result set:

```
fee sum_fi
--- ------
fo    NULL
fum    400
```

What I want is for the value returned for sum_fi to be NULL whenever an included value is NULL.  (This is different than the SUM aggregate function ignores NULL, and returns a total for the non-NULL expressions.)

Question: What query can I use to return the desired result set?

I don't find any built in aggregate function that exhibits this behavior.

Comment: similar question with marked solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288953/using-sum-so-that-null-in-columns-make-sum-null

Comment: Thanks Aaron, my search didn't find that question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about using `SUM(fi is NULL)` to determine if you have a NULL value in your data set?
This should work:

```
SELECT fee, IF(SUM(fi is NULL), NULL, SUM(fi)) AS sum_fi FROM t4 GROUP BY fee
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT fee, 
       IF(COUNT(fi) < (SELECT count(fee) FROM t4 temp2 WHERE temp1.fee = temp2.fee),
           NULL, SUM(fi)) AS sum_fi
FROM t4 temp1 GROUP BY fee
```

There is also this solution:

```
SELECT fee, CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(fi) THEN SUM(fi) ELSE NULL END AS sum_fi
FROM t4 GROUP BY fee
```

which I derived from the answer of the question Aaron W tagged as a duplicate of this. Admittedly, the latter form looks better than my original idea.

Comment: @spencer7593: The query had an error which I just fixed. Can you confirm?

Comment: I prefer the second form.  In my actual query (rather than the test case), the row source is not a simple `t4`, it is several tables joined with several predicates. I'd prefer not to repeat the specification for the t4 row source.