# Update row based on multiple relations

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

- Kits (kit_id, kit_weight)
- Kit_Components (kit_id, quantity, component_id)
- Components (component_id, weight)

For each entry in the kits table there can be one or more Kit_Component entries. Each component has a weight column which can either be the weight or null if we haven't weighed it yet. What I need to do is run an SQL query to update the weight column of the Kits table based on the total weight times quantity of all its components or if any of the weights are null set its value to null but I'm not even sure its possible, is it?

Note: I'd like to avoid scripts, triggers or procedures. I have code that does this when a component is saved or a kit is updated but I'd like to be able to do this in bulk.

---

EDIT: To further clarify I can SUM the weights * quantity however this doesn't deal with component rows being NULL as NULL acts as 0 in a SUM (I've tested this)

E.g. Kit1 has 1xComponentA with a weight of 14 and 2xComponentB with a weight of NULL

SELECT kit_id, SUM(component.weight * kit_component.quantity) FROM kit_component INNER JOIN component ON kit_component.component_id = component.id GROUP BY kit_component.kit_id

This would return 14 for kit1, however this is wrong because ComponentB has no weight so instead should return NULL.

[Hugo Kornelis](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/143223-question-about-sum-nulls):
"If the data in a group (as formed by GROUP BY) has some NULLs and some
non-NULL data, the NULLs are ignored and the result is the sum of the
remaining numbers: SUM {1, 3, NULL, 5} = SUM {1, 3, 5} = 9
If all data in the group is NULL, the NULLs are ignored as well, leaving
no rows to be summed at all: the result is the sum of the empty set; by
definition this is NULL. SUM {NULL, NULL} = SUM {} = NULL."

Comment: You will probably need an UPDATE statement. And a SUM() over an aggregating  subquery. And maybe even a multiplication!!!

Comment: why do you need the group by clause, you get what you want without it

Comment: @ilan-berci Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, your problems seem to be to make the following query return `NULL` when any value going into it is `NULL`:

```
SELECT kit_id, SUM(component.weight * kit_component.quantity)
FROM kit_component INNER JOIN
     component
     ON kit_component.component_id = component.id
GROUP BY kit_component.kit_id
```

You can do this with additional logic:

```
SELECT kit_id,
       (case when count(component.weight) = count(*) and
                  count(component.quantity) = count(*)
             then SUM(component.weight * kit_component.quantity)
        end)
FROM kit_component INNER JOIN
     component
     ON kit_component.component_id = component.id
GROUP BY kit_component.kit_id
```

Remember `count(<field>)` counts the number of non-NULL values in the field.  So, the counts are essentially saying "all values are non-null" or, equivalently, "no values are null".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes that's what I was looking for however I've found an alternative which I've also posted.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around a bit more I realised the problem was the way that SUM handles groupings that have some NULL values. After finding this post [SQL query to return NULL for SUM(expression) whenever an included value IS NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312703/sql-query-to-return-null-for-sumexpression-whenever-an-included-value-is-null) I have work out a resolution and it is as follows:

```
UPDATE kits
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        kit_id,
            IF(SUM(component.weight is NULL), NULL, SUM(component.weight * kit_component.quantity)) AS total_weight
    FROM
        kit_component
    INNER JOIN component ON kit_component.component_id = component.id
    GROUP BY kit_component.kit_id) AS weights ON kits.id = weights.kit_id 
SET 
    kits.weight = weights.total_weight
```

This will update the kits tables weight to null if any of its components weights are null or  total weight if all components have valid values.